# Why does chrome say this app doesn't have permission to call "management.get" despite having "management" permission?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

The manifest.json definitely has the "management" permission:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Test app",
    "description": "Communicates with apps",
    "version": "0.0.0.36",
    "minimum_chrome_version": "23",
    "offline_enabled": true,
    "icons": 
    {
        "16": "icon_16.png",
        "128": "icon_128.png"
    },
    "app": 
    {
        "background": 
        {
            "scripts": 
            [
                "main.js"
            ]
        }
    },
    "permissions": 
    [
        "unlimitedStorage",
        "fullscreen",
        "fileSystem.write",
        "background",
        "http://*/",
        "management"
    ],
    "update_url": "http://192.168.1.12/testapp.xml"
}
```

Why is it still throwing that error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only extensions may use the [`chrome.management`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management.html) API. What you've created is a Chrome App, which doesn't implement nor recognize the `management` permission (compare the [permissions of apps](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/declare_permissions.html) with the [permissions of extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions.html) to see the difference).

If you want to use the `management` API within an app, you need to publish a Chrome App *and* a Chrome extension, and use the [external message passing API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html#external) to communicate with each other.

Comment: Thanks. Any other way to discover if an extension or app actually exists?

Comment: @DonRhummy Do you manage the other apps/extension? If not, then there is no reliable other way. If yes, you can respond to [`chrome.runtime.sendMessage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime.html#method-sendMessage) calls, or expose a resource through the [`"web_accessible_resources"`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest.html#web_accessible_resources) section of the manifest file (and query that file using `XMLHttpRequest`).